# How to understand the error message for this code snippet?

Tags: java, eclipse, mahout

I need to work on a project using open source software, mahout. An example program
is as follows.

```
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.common.Refreshable;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.common.FastIDSet;
import org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.similarity.ItemSimilarity;
public class GenderItemSimilarity implements ItemSimilarity {

   private final FastIDSet men;
   private final FastIDSet women;
   public GenderItemSimilarity(FastIDSet men, FastIDSet women) {
       this.men = men;
       this.women = women;
   }

   public double itemSimilarity(long profileID1, long profileID2) {
      Boolean profile1IsMan = isMan(profileID1);
      if (profile1IsMan == null) {
      return 0.0;
   }
   Boolean profile2IsMan = isMan(profileID2);
      if (profile2IsMan == null) {
        return 0.0;
      }
   return profile1IsMan == profile2IsMan ? 1.0 : -1.0;
   }

 public double[] itemSimilarities(long itemID1, long[] itemID2s) {
    double[] result = new double[itemID2s.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < itemID2s.length; i++) {
     result[i] = itemSimilarity(itemID1, itemID2s[i]);
    }
   return result;
 }

private Boolean isMan(long profileID) {
  if (men.contains(profileID)) {
  return Boolean.TRUE;
 }
if (women.contains(profileID)) {
    return Boolean.FALSE;
  }
   return null;
}

public void refresh(Collection<Refreshable> alreadyRefreshed) {
  // do nothing
 }
}
```

The eclipse compiler gives the error message such as

> The type GenderItemSimilarity must implement the inherited abstract method  ItemSimilarity.allSimilarItemIDs(long)

It seems to me that this error message indicates that there exists a class ItemSimilarity, which has a method of allSimilarItemIDs(long).  However, the current program does not have this method. Is my analysis correct? Will adding this kind of method solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet from the book Mahout in Action. (I'm an author.) I don't think this is the complete, latest source code that accompanies the book. Make sure to get the latest, which at the moment is not at Manning, but lives (and will live) on [Github](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/tree/).

Comment: Thanks, Sean. Yes, that's the code from Mahout in Action. I am trying to learn it and start to work on my project based on Mahout. I will check the latest code from Github.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the `ItemSimilarity` class declares an abstract method called `allSimilarItemIDs`.  As you're implementing this class, you must define a method body for that abstract method in your class.

Comment: (or make your class abstract too, so that it becomes the responsibility of someone who implements your class, but that probably isn't what you want to do).

Answer (score 0):

From the error message we could understand that ItemSimilarity interface is having a method called allSimilarItemIDs(long) which we need to handle also..

Just for testing purpose once implement this method by adding a simple print statement.
If it solves this then we can easily understand what the problem is..